# Oracle sql, ora is thrown: group function is not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle, exception

I want to execute following SQL script

```
SELECT 
    t1.Technology, 
    count(t1.trax_id) as "Current number of items",  
    TO_CHAR(MAX(TO_DATE('20000101','yyyymmdd') +
       (SYSDATE - t1.time_event)),'hh24:mi:ss') as "max_ages"
FROM 
    dm_procmon t1
GROUP BY
    t1.Technology, count(t1.trax_id), 
    TO_CHAR(MAX(TO_DATE('20000101','yyyymmdd') +
       (SYSDATE - t1.time_event)), 'hh24:mi:ss')
HAVING 
    COUNT(t1.trax_id) = 1;
```

When I execute it following exception is thrown

> Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 7
>   Error report - SQL Error:
>   ORA-00934: Groepsfunctie is hier niet toegestaan.
>   00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `aggregate` function in `group by`. Remove the aggregate function `count` from `group by`.

```
SELECT t1.Technology,
       Count(t1.trax_id)                                                                         AS "Current number of items",
       To_char(Max(To_date('20000101', 'yyyymmdd') + ( SYSDATE - t1.time_event )), 'hh24:mi:ss') AS "max_ages"
FROM   dm_procmon t1
GROUP  BY t1.Technology
HAVING Count(t1.trax_id) = 1;
```

Comment: @user4663023 - Missed to check the max function updated try now